# For returns Unit

Tags: scala

I want to zip the index of a month with its name:

```
  val res = for(i <- 1 to 12) {
    val m = DateTime.parse(i.toString, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("mm").withLocale(Locale.US))
    yield (i, m.monthOfYear().getAsString)
  }
```

Why `res` is `Unit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a better way of doing this:

```
val res = (1 to 12) map { i =>
    val m = DateTime.parse(i.toString, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("mm").withLocale(Locale.US))
    (i, m.monthOfYear().getAsString)
  }
```

But your for doesn't work because "yield" keyword should be outside of "for".

```
 val res = for {
     i <- 1 to 12
     m = DateTime.parse(i.toString, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("mm").withLocale(Locale.US))
  } yield (i, m.monthOfYear().getAsString)
```

Comment: why are you using toList in the first case? It's needless.

Comment: you are right, `Range` is a monad and has it's own map method

Answer (score 6):

Your for comprehension should be:

```
val res = for(
    i <- 1 to 12;
    m = DateTime.parse(i.toString, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("mm").withLocale(Locale.US))
) yield (i, m.monthOfYear().getAsString)
```

The code you have given does not compile, however if you have a `for` expression of the form

```
for(i <- 1 to 12) {
   ...
}
```

this is converted into

```
1.to(12).foreach(i => ... )
```

which returns `Unit`, which is why `res` is `Unit` in your code.

You need to use `yield` to create a projection.